# Continue screen recording even after screen turns off

Tags: ipados, screen-recording

I was screen recording with my iPad Pro and in the middle of it, I accidentally turned off my screen. I finished what I was doing and wanted to stop the screen recording but to my surprise it was already off.

I checked the resulting video and I only recorded up to the time I accidentally turned off my screen.

Is there a way for me to instruct the screen recorder to continue recording even when the screen is off?

Answer (score 1):

**No**

There are no options for screen recording in the settings app. You also get a little notification that the recording has been stopped after you set the device to sleep.

---

If you own a Mac you could use QuickTime player to record the screen. Connect your device to the Mac with a cable then open QuickTime Player, right click on the icon in dock, select `new recording` and set the input to your mobile device (small `arrow` next to the red record-button). Then click `record`. It will continue the recording even though you set the mobile device to sleep.

Comment: I do not own a Mac so I can't try this out but upvoted. Thanks!